# What is this insect (Egypt)?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I am from Egypt, and I found this insect in my house. It's slow when it moves, and I didn't see it fly. It's green (my phone camera didn't get the colors right).
 [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is some species of [aphid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphididae).

Most people are familiar with the wingless stages of these insects that crawl on and eat plants. There are also winged '[alates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alate)'. For example, see the life cycle of the soybean aphid:

[image]

Due to the picture quality, I'm uncertain about the exact species. However, I can show you alates from some similar looking species:

***Nasonovia ribisnigri*** ([**Currant-lettuce aphid**](http://aphid.aphidnet.org/Nasonovia_ribisnigri.php))

[image]

<sup>Source: [influentialpoints.com](http://influentialpoints.com/Gallery/Nasonovia_ribisnigri_Currant-lettuce_aphid.htm)</sup>

***Aphis pomis*** ([**Green Apple Aphid**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphis_pomi))

[image]

<sup>[Source](http://www.plante-doktor.dk/groen%20aeblebladlus.htm)</sup>

***Macrosiphum rosae*** ([**Rose Aphid**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macrosiphum_rosae))

[image]

<sup>Source: [Bernard Dupont](https://www.flickr.com/photos/berniedup/16603373114/)</sup>

As you can see, these phenotypic characteristics (i.e., green body with black head, clear wings, black/green striped legs, green [cauda](http://aphid.aphidnet.org/cauda.php) and black [cornicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornicle)) are present in numerous diverse species of aphids.

Perhaps you could comment on nearby crop plants or garden plants near your house or produce that you've recently purchased or brought into the house. Sometimes knowing possible host plant species can help narrow down possibilities.